# Spanish translation of Adversity Quotient?

Tags: translation

I was reading the book *Adversity Quotient* by Dr. Paul G. Stoltz and I would like to make a gift with that book to someone, but that person is not fluent in English (they're a Spanish citizen). Is there any translation of this book into Spanish? I've searched, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited your question since recommendation questions are off-topic here: it's fine to ask whether a particular book has been translated, but not to ask for a list/recommendation of books of a particular type/topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking for a translation of a self-help book is not asking about it as literature, and since the book in question is not "inherently" literature I think this tips into off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips for finding these sorts of things include clicking on the author's name on amazon or looking in Goodreads (selecting all editions under a title will surface many but not necessarily all translations of a book—you would still need to also look over the author's whole output by going to their author page).

From that, I was able to find a Russian translation of the book (*Показатель стойкости: как обратить препятствия в новые возможности*) and what might be a Vietnamese edition (*AQ - Chỉ Số Vượt Khó*), but no Spanish edition. I suspect that no Spanish translation of the book has been made as of yet.